# first_value function with IGNORE NULLS expression is not working on Athena AWS

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I've used `fist_value` function, it works fine but when I added "IGNORE NULLS" I got the following error

> line 1:179: mismatched input ')'. Expecting: 'OVER'

My function:

```
first_value (if(DiffconvCompView  = 0,null,DiffconvCompView)  ignore nulls) OVER (partition by Widget_id, User_country, Domain order by date desc , hour desc  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 0 PRECEDING  )
```

So I looked at the documentation and the syntax looks fine.

```
FIRST_VALUE | LAST_VALUE
( expression [ IGNORE NULLS | RESPECT NULLS ] ) OVER
(
[ PARTITION BY expr_list ]
[ ORDER BY order_list frame_clause ]
)
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_first_value.html

So why I get an error?

Answer (score 3):

Athena uses [Presto](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/presto-functions.html), not Redshift, so use `ignore nulls` after closing brace of `first_value`:

```sql
first_value(if(DiffconvCompView = 0, null, DiffconvCompView)) ignore nulls OVER (...))
```